# How to update a field using a converter and ajax in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml, converters

I basically have two input field I display if the value is currently empty or null. if it is not, I display an outputText. Those two values are currency values stored in a Long object and I use a converter to display the data properly (I can't use PrimeFaces' inputNumber since I am using PrimeFaces 5.3). My problem is the following :

```
<c:set var="edtVal1" value="#{bean.val1 ne null and bean.val1 ne 0}" scope="request" />
<c:set var="edtVal2" value="#{bean.val2 ne null and bean.val2 ne 0}" scope="request" />

<p:panelGrid>
    <p:row>
        <p:column colspan="2">
            <p:messages id="mainMessages" globalOnly="false" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" />
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
    <!-- [...] -->

    <p:row>
        <p:column styleClass="col-quarter col-label2">
            <h:outputText value="value 1" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column styleClass="col-quarter col-value2" rendered="#{edtVal1}">
            <h:outputText id="val1Output" value="#{bean.val1}" converter="myConverter" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column styleClass="col-quarter" rendered="#{not edtVal1}">
            <p:inputText id="val1Input" value="#{bean.val1}" converter="myConverter">
                <p:ajax update="mainMessages val1Input" event="change" />
            </p:inputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
    <p:row>
        <p:column styleClass="col-quarter col-label2">
            <h:outputText value="value 2" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column styleClass="col-quarter col-value2" rendered="#{edtVal2}">
            <h:outputText id="val1Output" value="#{bean.val2}" converter="myConverter" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column styleClass="col-quarter" rendered="#{not edtVal2}">
            <p:inputText id="val1Input" value="#{bean.val2}" converter="myConverter">
                <p:ajax update="mainMessages val1Input" event="change" />
            </p:inputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

when I put it like this, the messages thrown by the converter are displayed, but none of the fields are updated. However, if I use the same boolean variable for both input/output options (changed the variable used in `rendered` attribute of the 1rst data row to use `edtVal2` in both) like so :

```
<p:row>
    <p:column styleClass="col-quarter col-label2">
        <h:outputText value="value 1" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column styleClass="col-quarter col-value2" rendered="#{edtVal1}">
        <h:outputText id="val1Output" value="#{bean.val1}" converter="myConverter" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column styleClass="col-quarter" rendered="#{not edtVal1}">
        <p:inputText id="val1Input" value="#{bean.val1}" converter="myConverter">
            <p:ajax update="mainMessages val1Input" event="change" />
        </p:inputText>
    </p:column>
</p:row>
```

The first field updates successfully and the second once still does not work.

Using a converter to display a formated data is a workaround I already done and it works just as expected and I use the same converter than before. But this time, I don't understand why it's not working.

The converter is important to reproduce the issue, but any custom converter seems to do the job.

Comment: You should seriously improve your title... Read [ask], it contains suggestions on how to write a good title. And read [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: I agree the question is quite long, but it is minimal : my problem has a blurry cause and I tried to solve it for 2 hours. I don't think this question deserves a downvote, especially with the effort I made to formulate the question as accurately as possible.

Comment: But still, you should add some text to explain the differences between the first and second 'panelgrid'. Now it is up to the people willing to help to find the differences and it is not an [mcve] ;-)

Comment: Would I need to remove the Converter code to be minimal?

Comment: If you don't need the converter to have the same problem, you can remove it. But it also needs to be complete, verifyable... Create an empty jsf project. copy/paste in there what you posted above. Does it run? Also read http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: I do need the converter for the whole situation because the field should update itself in the good format. The converter acts as a validator in the same time. I doubt it causes the problem though. So maybe I could remove it and just say that the converter takes the text value, cleans it and displays the value in the proper format. what do you think is best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any other solutions are still welcome on this post, but I managed to find a working solution :

when I changed the `rendered` attribute to a constant string, the issue was absent. So I think the problem comes from a misunderstanding of `<c:set>`.

My solution was to use a the bean as a controller. I changed the variables from the xhtml file to properties in the controller and now everything works fine. So I removed all `<c:set>` from my xhtml and use a proper MVC pattern on that page now.

---

Note :
For those who don't know what MVC is : it's a neat architectural pattern that divides clearly the user interface and manipulated data. Learn more  [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).